# encrypt ASP(Rijndael), Descrypt in php

Tags: encryption, rijndael

I have a code in ASP, but I dont know encrypt in php and compare the password encrypted.

My library is:

```
   using System.Security.Cryptography;

    // Encrypt a string into a string using a password 

    //    Uses Encrypt(byte[], byte[], byte[]) 

    public string Encrypt(string clearText, string Password)
    {

        // First we need to turn the input string into a byte array. 

        byte[] clearBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);



        // Then, we need to turn the password into Key and IV 

        // We are using salt to make it harder to guess our key using a dictionary attack - 

        // trying to guess a password by enumerating all possible words. 

        PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password,

                    new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });



        // Now get the key/IV and do the encryption using the function that accepts byte arrays. 

        // Using PasswordDeriveBytes object we are first getting 32 bytes for the Key 

        // (the default Rijndael key length is 256bit = 32bytes) and then 16 bytes for the IV. 

        // IV should always be the block size, which is by default 16 bytes (128 bit) for Rijndael. 

        // If you are using DES/TripleDES/RC2 the block size is 8 bytes and so should be the IV size. 

        // You can also read KeySize/BlockSize properties off the algorithm to find out the sizes. 

        byte[] encryptedData = Encrypt(clearBytes, pdb.GetBytes(32), pdb.GetBytes(16));



        // Now we need to turn the resulting byte array into a string. 

        // A common mistake would be to use an Encoding class for that. It does not work 

        // because not all byte values can be represented by characters. 

        // We are going to be using Base64 encoding that is designed exactly for what we are 

        // trying to do. 

        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);

    }
```

and php code is:

```
function fnEncrypt($Word, $key){

    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv( mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND );

    if (strlen($iv_base64 = rtrim(base64_encode($iv), '=')) != 22) return false;

    $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $Word . md5($Word), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));

    return $iv_base64 . $encrypted;
}
```

or I tried use this code in php:

```
function Encrypt($pass, $salt){

    $derived = PBKDF1($pass, $salt, 100, 32);
    $key = bin2hex(substr($derived, 0, 32));
    $iv = bin2hex(substr($derived, 32, 16));
    return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $pass, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
}
function PBKDF1($pass, $salt, $count, $dklen)
{
     $t = sha1($pass.$salt);
    for($i=1; $i <= $count; $i++)
    {
        $t = sha1($t);
    }
    $t = substr($t,0,$dklen-1);
    return $t;
}
```

but not working, I hope I can help.

Excuse me for my bad english

Comment: What is not working? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: the encrypted code not is the same and every time you refresh the page, the encrypted code is not the same.

Comment: I have the encrypted code the ASP, but the encrypted code that generates the function is not the same

Comment: Does this behavior happen in both ASP.net and PHP?
What exactly is not the same?

Comment: this is the result I want to get:     
//Generate Code ASP
test1234 ---> lHnAMv96LgP4/0v6rI9WS7ayNB/i/G6jH5VNMY5Rvzo=

//Parameters
$Word = "test1234";
echo fnEncrypt($Word, $key);

//Or use
echo base64_encode(Encrypt($key, $Word));

is not the same encrypted code

Comment: Yes, is APS.NET the original encrypted code test1234 ---> lHnAMv96LgP4/0v6rI9WS7ayNB/i/G6jH5VNMY5Rvzo=

Comment: I noticed this line `$iv = mcrypt_create_iv( mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND );` Are you making sure to use the same IV for encryption and decryption? If they are different decryption will fail.

Comment: @Patashu, this is probably the problem with the first PHP sample. In ASP.net you are using a fixed generation seed. new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });

Comment: that's the problem, that the IV is generated by the asp code and not what is. Used this function in ASP.NET but not how emulate it in php.
using System.Security.Cryptography;

//ASP Code            // Then, we need to turn the password into Key and IV 

            // We are using salt to make it harder to guess our key using a dictionary attack - 

            // trying to guess a password by enumerating all possible words. 

            PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });

Comment: The IV must be the same in both ASP and PHP. If it cannot be predictably generated, it must be stored (e.g. in database) or passed (e.g. with message data) from one to the other. If it is still failing when the IV, data and key are the same, the algorithm is wrong - make sure that not only do you take all the same steps, you take them the right number, in the reversed order, and the correct reversals of each step (Debugging output may help if you are not sure)

Comment: is what I will do, thank you very much, but it works I will write again, than you

Comment: I was reviewing the code of ASP, and the IV is generated by an array, but do not understand how to apply it to the function as written...

function Encrypt($pass, $salt){

    $derived = PBKDF1($pass, $salt, 100, 32);
    $key = bin2hex(substr($derived, 0, 32));
    $iv = bin2hex(substr($derived, 32, 16));
    return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $pass, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
}
function PBKDF1($pass, $salt, $count, $dklen)
{
     $t = sha1($pass.$salt);
    for($i=1; $i <= $count; $i++)
    {
        $t = sha1($t);
    }
    $t = substr($t,0,$dklen-1);
    return $t;
}

Comment: this is array {Dimensions:[16]}
    [0]: 163
    [1]: 142
    [2]: 208
    [3]: 119
    [4]: 214
    [5]: 117
    [6]: 68
    [7]: 49
    [8]: 14
    [9]: 10
    [10]: 111
    [11]: 178
    [12]: 110
    [13]: 173
    [14]: 241
    [15]: 216